# How to set a background light to a button on Android?

Tags: android, animation, button, effects

I want add a effect to on my buttons on android that includes light or only ı may add a light too  in this context ı want to ask  how to set a backround light to a button on android ?

Comment: what do you mean by background light ?
use can use android:background="" in your layout

Comment: can you post a screen shot of desired layout?

Comment: ı mean when ı press the button user can feel presssed that button and ı want to assure this with light ( when user press button can shine or light may occur on the button )

Comment: You can use selector.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For changing the background of a button**

1. design your background in a picture or download the picture
   that you want to place it for the background.
2. Place the image in the ***res/drawable***(make sure the name of file contains lower case only)
3. Goto xml file of the button and write
   `android:background="@drawable/FILENAME` replace FILENAME by the name of the picture placed in ***drawable***.

I hope this changes the background of the button.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the background color of the button on the click event. If you want to change the button programmatically then you can set up an onClick listener or in your xml (XML is usually easier). I also sometimes simply hide the button to show it was clicked but to also avoid a second click that might cause problems.

Here is an example of a programmatic onClick listener:

```
Button button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Button oneButton;

    // Set the button clicked to a different color
    v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_selected));
  }
});
```